# How should be configured a MVC web app to work with Azure Storage?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, visual-studio, azure

I have this almost template code to get my blob container to upload some supports

```
    public CloudBlobContainer GetCloudBlobContainer()
        {
            CloudStorageAccount storageAccount = CloudStorageAccount.Parse(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["GYPFileStorage"]);
            CloudBlobClient blobClient = storageAccount.CreateCloudBlobClient();
            CloudBlobContainer blobContainer = blobClient.GetContainerReference("files");
            try
            {
                if (blobContainer.CreateIfNotExists()) //Exception
                {
                    blobContainer.SetPermissions(new BlobContainerPermissions { PublicAccess = BlobContainerPublicAccessType.Blob });
                }
            }catch(Exception ex)
            {
                System.Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
            }
            return blobContainer;
        }
```

The problem is that I'm getting a couple of exception depending on my Web.config

If I don't change it @ all I get this:

**Error creating the web proxy specified in the 'system.net/defaultproxy' configuration section**

I browsed around and found a couple of fixes of the kind:

```
    <system.net>
     <defaultProxy enabled="false" useDefaultCredentials="false">
      <proxy/>
      <bypasslist/>
      <module/>
     </defaultProxy>
    </system.net>
```

This is the one that has at least changed the exception to:

**the type initializer for 'system.net.servicepointmanager' threw an exception**

What am I doing wrong? what config should I try?

I'm testing on the Azure Storage Emulator 4.6 and have installed Azure SDK 2.9

Comment: Are you sure your GYPFileStorage is valid azure storage account connection?

Comment: Yep, I debugged all the way til the exception and it gets the account and client ok

Comment: probably a web.config issue. can you add it? (even without values)

Comment: I have the default web.config from the template, the only variation I'm adding is the mark up u see up there

Comment: Hi @Moonzenith you're getting this error locally or after deploy to Azure?

Comment: HI @ThiagoCustodio, I'm getting the error on both

Comment: @Moonzenith it's not related to Azure SDK, but it's a network issue. Your proxy is blocking that, however you should not receive this kind of error on Azure, since it should be able to access it's own network with no problems. Try to capture the request through Fiddler. Then try to change your network settings and replay the request until you fix that. There's not much else to do besides set your proxy credentials / allow on your firewall rules.

Comment: @ThiagoCustodio Well... "Solved" ... I just remade everything. made a new project, imported all my model, controllers, NuGet and stuff and now it works... Web.Config is same thing in both projects. I Think It was just Visual Studio being picky ~.~

Comment: I glad to hear that @Moonzenith. Cheers,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to all the people that took a look on this issue, I solved it by making a new project and importing my stuff. Now it is working, did nothing different but as long as it works...